# setbeamertemplage + beamerarticle = bug

Tags: beamer, beamerarticle

I've tried to use the package `beamerarticle` to get notes from my teaching slides.

It seems that beamerarticle has a problem parsing the file with setbeamertemplate commands that have bracket arguments.

In the (almost minimal) example below, the command `\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[square]` is simply ignored in beamerarticle mode.

When the command has two bracket arguments (like in the two other commands), it is worse: the second argument is considered plain text and thus the compiler outputs a "missing \begin{document} error though it is still parsing the preamble.

No error happens with the same doc when the documentclass is `beamer`.

MWE:

```
% Case 1 : beamer original : no problem
%\documentclass{beamer} 

% Case 2 :  beamerarticle mode : compilation issue
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{beamerarticle}

\usetheme{Hannover} 

%-- beamer setup

% a command that compiles ok in both mode, but with no effect in beameraritcle ??
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[square]

% a command that compiles in beamer, but produces error in beamerarticle
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas left}[vertical shading][top=structure.fg!50,bottom=structure.fg!10]

%another one
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow]

%--end beamer setup


\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{A first frame}{}
\begin{itemize}
\item toto
\end{itemize}


\begin{block}{titleblock}
a bloc
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Hi @pierre my approach is follow the pages 210-213 of [beamer user guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) for work with the package `beamerarticle`.

Firstly, we create a file `main.article.tex`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\setjobnamebeamerversion{main.beamer}
\input{main}
```

Secondly, we create a file `main.beamer.tex`:

```latex
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}
\input{main}
```

And lastly, we create a file `main.tex`:

```latex
\mode<article>{
    \usepackage{fullpage}
    }

\mode<presentation>{
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[square]
    \setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas left}[vertical shading][top=structure.fg!50,bottom=structure.fg!10]
    \setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
    \usetheme{Hannover}
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{A first frame}{}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item toto
    \end{itemize}

    \begin{block}{titleblock}
        a bloc
    \end{block}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

We compile `main.artice.tex` and looks like

[image]

We compile `main.beamer.tex` and looks like

[image]

There are my suggest but I do not know if you want work by separate files.